# An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker when saving changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, ef-code-first, repository, http-post

I have two domain objects, both identical but with different PK properties:

```
public partial class Maintenance : MaintenanceBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int MaintenanceId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}

public partial class MyMaintenance : MaintenanceBase
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int RowId { get; set; }

    public virtual Employee Employee { get; set; }
}
```

The rest of the properties are inherited from a base class. The problem I am having is when try to call save changes in my post controller, I am getting the following error:

```
An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker
```

This is (basically) my controller method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SubmitMyMaintenance(IList<MyMaintenance> myMaintenanceList, string userName)
    {
        foreach (var result in myMaintenanceList)
    {
    var m = iMyMaintenanceRepository.GetSingle(result.RowId);
    Maintenance maintenance = new Maintenance();

    // Use Injector to handle mapping between viewmodel and model
    maintenance.InjectFrom(m);

    try
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // save the maintenance item
            iMaintenanceRepository.Add(maintenance);
            iMaintenanceRepository.Save();

            // delete the item in MyMaintenance
            iMyMaintenanceRepository.Delete(m);
            iMyMaintenanceRepository.Save();
        }
    }
    catch (DataException ex)
    {
        message = ex.InnerException.ToString();
    }
}

// refresh the view 
var mvm = new MyMaintenanceListViewModel
{
    MyMaintenanceList = iMyMaintenanceRepository.FindBy(v => v.CreatedBy.Equals(userName)).ToList(),
    Message = "Your maintenance items were successfully added."
};

return View("MyMaintenance", mvm);

}
```

I suspect this is because I have instances of respositories (`iMaintenanceRepository` & `iMyMaintenanceRepository`) for both domain objects in the same controller post method, and both have a reference to the Employee entity.

For instance, when I dispose the iMyMaintenanceRepository and create a new instance (before refreshing the view at the end), I get en error about inserting a null value in the Employee table, which I am not inserting anything. That is the reason I suspect the Employee entity exists in two different data contexts. I am not sure how to resolve it though. None of the solutions I have found seem to apply and I am thinking it is more of an implementation problem on my part.

**EDIT: Repositories**

```
namespace EMMS.Models.Interfaces
{
    public interface IMyMaintenanceRepository : IGenericRepository<MyMaintenance>
    {
        MyMaintenance GetSingle(int RowId);
    }
}

namespace EMMS.Models.Repositories
{
    public class MyMaintenanceRepository : GenericRepository<AppDBContext, MyMaintenance>, IMyMaintenanceRepository
    {
        public MyMaintenance GetSingle(int RowId)
        {
            var query = GetAll().FirstOrDefault(x => x.RowId == RowId);
            return query;
        }
    }
}

namespace EMMS.ViewModels.Repositories
{
    public class GenericRepository<C, T> : IDisposable, IGenericRepository<T>
        where T : class
        where C : DbContext, new()
    {
        private C _entities = new C();
        public C Context
        {
            get { return _entities; }
            set { _entities = value; }
        }

        public virtual IQueryable<T> GetAll()
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>();
            return query;
        }

        public IQueryable<T> FindBy(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            return query;
        }

        // enforce referential itegrity
        public bool ValueInUse(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            IQueryable<T> query = _entities.Set<T>().Where(predicate);
            int count = query.Count();
            return count > 0 ? true : false;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Set<T>().Add(entity);
        }

        public virtual void Delete(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Deleted;
        }

        public virtual void Edit(T entity)
        {
            _entities.Entry(entity).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
        }

        public virtual void Save()
        {
            _entities.SaveChanges();
        }

        private bool disposed = false; // to detect redundant calls
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (!disposed)
            {
                if (disposing)
                {
                    if (_entities != null)
                    {
                        _entities.Dispose();
                    }
                }

                disposed = true;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }
    }
}

namespace EMMS.ViewModels.Interfaces
{
    public interface IGenericRepository<T> where T : class
    {
        IQueryable<T> GetAll();
        IQueryable<T> FindBy(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        bool ValueInUse(System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        void Add(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Edit(T entity);
        void Save();
        void Dispose();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolute correct about the issue. Actually, in particular, it's because each repository has it's own instance of your context object, and you're trying to pass an `Employee` that was originally retrieved via one instance and saving it via different instance.

The easiest solution is to track all like things in one repository. In other words, just use one `MaintenanceRepository` can have calls to return both `Maintenance` and `MyMaintenance`. Though that stretches the idea of a "repository" a bit. This is why repositories are typically combined with a Unit of Work class, which would house the context for the repositories to share. However, at that point, you're basically just recreating the structure Entity Framework already implements. So, holding everything in just one "repository" makes more sense, but now you're really talking about a "service" pattern rather than a repository pattern. It's just semantics though.

**UPDATE**

*Disclaimer: This is what I'm using currently in a project and it works for me. This may not be the best practice and reasonable people could very well disagree with my approach.*

**`IService` Interface**

```
public interface IService<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetById(int id, string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetOne(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetFirst(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    TEntity GetLast(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "");
    void Create(TEntity entity);
    void Update(TEntity entity);
    void Delete(int id);
    void Delete(TEntity entity);
    int Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null);
    bool Any(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null);
}
```

**`Service`, Implementation of `IService`**

```
public class Service<TContext, TEntity> : IService<TContext, TEntity>
    where TContext : DbContext
    where TEntity : class
{
    internal TContext context;
    internal DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public Service(TContext context)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> GetAll(
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return Get(null, orderBy, includeProperties);
    }

    public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Get(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;

        if (filter != null)
        {
            query = query.Where(filter);
        }

        foreach (var includeProperty in includeProperties.Split
            (new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
        {
            query = query.Include(includeProperty);
        }

        if (orderBy != null)
        {
            return orderBy(query).ToList();
        }
        else
        {
            return query.Distinct().ToList();
        }
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetById(int id, string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return dbSet.Find(id);
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetOne(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return Get(filter, null, includeProperties).SingleOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetFirst(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties).FirstOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual TEntity GetLast(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null,
        Func<IQueryable<TEntity>, IOrderedQueryable<TEntity>> orderBy = null,
        string includeProperties = "")
    {
        return Get(filter, orderBy, includeProperties).LastOrDefault();
    }

    public virtual void Create(TEntity entity)
    {
        dbSet.Add(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(int id)
    {
        var entity = GetById(id);
        Delete(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Delete(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        dbSet.Remove(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Update(TEntity entity)
    {
        if (context.Entry(entity).State == EntityState.Detached)
        {
            dbSet.Attach(entity);
        }
        context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
    }

    public virtual int Count(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return Get(filter).Count();
    }

    public virtual bool Any(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter = null)
    {
        return Count(filter) > 0;
    }
}
```

**`ServiceGroup`, Abstract container for services**

```
public abstract class ServiceGroup<TContext> : IDisposable
    where TContext : DbContext
{
    protected TContext context;

    public virtual void Save()
    {
        try
        {
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException validationException)
        {
            string validationErrorMessage = DbEntityValidationMessageParser.GetErrorMessage(validationException);
            Console.WriteLine(validationErrorMessage);
        }

    }

    #region Disposable
    private bool disposed = false;

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                context.Dispose();
            }
        }
        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

So, the way I use this all is whenever I want to create a collection of like things to work with, I subclass `ServiceGroup` like so:

```
public class SampleService : ServiceGroup<MyDbContext>
{
    public SampleService()
    {
        this.context = new MyDbContext();
    }

    private Service<MyDbContext, SomeModel> someModels;
    public Service<MyDbContext, SomeModel> SomeModels
    {
        get
        {
            if (someModels == null)
            {
                someModels = new Service<MyDbContext, SomeModel>(context);
            }
            return someModels;
        }
    }

    private Service<MyDbContext, AnotherModel> anotherModels;
    public Service<MyDbContext, AnotherModel> AnotherModels
    {
        get
        {
            if (anotherModels == null)
            {
                anotherModels = new Service<MyDbContext, AnotherModel>(context);
            }
            return anotherModels;
        }
    }

    // rinse and repeat

}
```

This makes sure everything is using the same context instance. So to actually use it, you just do:

```
var service = new SampleService();

someModels = service.SomeModels.GetAll();
```

Comment: Thanks Chris. I will have to look into combining the two repositories. I edited my post to included the two repositories and the generic one they implement. If you have any suggestions as to how to combine them I would be grateful.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks again Chris. I will look at your solution.

Answer (score 0):

So I was searching the web for a complete example of a code first MVC implementation with repositories, unit of work, viewmodels, etc, and I found exactly what I was looking for here:

[EFMVC - ASP.NET MVC 4, Entity Framework 5 Code First and Windows Azure](http://efmvc.codeplex.com/)

This is a great demo web app that does everything I need from an architectural standpoint. I don't understand half of it, though, (yet) and it took me about 4 hours of retooling my app, but man was it worth it! It also solved my IEntityChangeTracker error.